# convert Stream object to an ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, wcf

Let me explain the whole scenario first.
This is my code on iOS side.

```
    NSMutableArray * myarr= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *str1=@"hello";
NSString *str2=@"Waleed";
NSString *str3=@"whatsup";
NSData *mydata=[str1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *mydata2=[str2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *mydata3=[str3 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[myarr addObject:mydata];
[myarr addObject:mydata2];
[myarr addObject:mydata3];
NSData *bigdata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myarr];
NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.249.1/service/GetEmployees.svc/ArrayUpload/";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

//add image data to POST
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:bigdata]];

[request setHTTPBody: postBody];

// connect to the web
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *respStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:respData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This code takes three different strings, converts all of them in NSData, put NSData objects them them in a MutableArray and then converts that MutableArray back to NSData in order to post it through WCF web sevice.

Now on C# I have this funtion in which that NSData (converted NSMutableArray) is received in a Stream object

```
public string ArrayUpload(Stream stream)
    {
    //code here
    }
```

now that stream object will have that NSData of Array.
I want to extract that array and then all those strings one by one. 
anyone who can help please?

Comment: You can't.  A stream is an array of byte[]/char[] and without inserting a separator you can't separate the individual object.  When sending data you must use one or more of the following methods 1) ASCII : terminate each object with a know character like '\n' 2)  ASCII or Binary : Add a byte count to beginning of each object 3) ASCII or Binary : Fixed length data.  Each object has know length so the objects  can be separated.

Comment: @jdweng if I dont have fixed length data, then? can you please simplify the code for me as i am new to objective c.

Comment: Why not use JSON?  It is supported directly in both iOS and .Net

Comment: @Paulw11 how to use it? can you please help? I am new to ios.

Comment: The ios class is `NSJsonSerializer` - you can pass it an array or dictionary and get back a JSON object (text).  In .Net you can use DataContractJsonSerializer - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The simplest way is to add a semicolon between objects and treat as CSV.